# Java game. need to stop the code without using break statement or system.exit

Tags: java

for the following code, I need to stop the code by typing the word "quit", but without using "break" or "system.exit" statements. anyone can help me out? I think boolean could solve this but i have no idea how to use it.
I placed the quit statement in the first two lines of the loop, 
but im not sure if it belongs there. Im in my learning phase, so dont be too strict :))

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game {


public static void main (String[]args){

    Game guessing = new Game();
    guessing.start();

}
public void start() {

    System.out.println("Welcome to guessing game!"); 
    System.out.println("Please enter the number between 1 and 1000");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playerName;
    String currentGuess;
    String quit = "quit";
boolean playGame = true;
int tries = 0;  //number of times player guessed

int guess = 0;  //number that player inputs

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  //start timer after first guess

int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1); // generating random number
System.out.println(randomNumber);     // to be deleted after game is finished

currentGuess = input.nextLine();


do{

if (currentGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(quit)) {

        System.out.println("Thanx for playing");}


    if (currentGuess.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        int PlayerGuessInt = Integer.parseInt(currentGuess);
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("You have netered non-numeric value,please try again");
    currentGuess = input.nextLine();
    continue;
    }

    guess = Integer.parseInt(currentGuess);


    if(guess<1 || guess>1000 ){

        System.out.println("The number is out of range! Please try again");
        currentGuess = input.nextLine();
        continue;
    }

    if (guess>randomNumber){
        System.out.println("Oops,too high!");
        currentGuess = input.nextLine();
        tries++;
    }
    else if (guess<randomNumber){
        System.out.println("Sorry, to low!");
        currentGuess = input.nextLine();
        tries++;
    }



}

while (guess!=randomNumber);


    if (guess==randomNumber){
        tries++;
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long gameTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Well done! You won the game in " + tries + " guesses " + "and " + gameTime/1000 +  " seconds!");
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        playerName = input.nextLine();

        }




}
}
```

Comment: You don't need that `if` after the `while` with an opposite condition since there are no `break` statements inside the while. It'll always be `true`.

Comment: Make the boolean part of your loop condition and set it to false when you want the loop to stop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I`m not sure what i mean, im a bit confused since its my first experience. all i know is that the game must stop when i type quit.

Comment: In this case `return;` or `System.exit(0);` will do that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey no, as i wrote in question, im not allowed to use break; or System.exit(0);

Comment: @user1703849 Then don't use it, use `return;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while loop so that it checks for the value of current guess being "quit". That way it will stop looping when the quit command is given e.g.

```
while(guess!=randomNumber && !currentGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(quit))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put inside the while in one (or all of the if )

```
if (currentGuess.equals("quit") {
   playGame = false
}
```

and change the while to be:

```
while (guess!=randomNumber && playGame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:
Global boolean variable:

```
bool userWantsToQuit = false;
```

so if someone types int quit (shouln't it be "quit" because it's string?)

```
if (currentGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(quit)) 
{
    userWantsToQuit = true; // we mark that someone wants to quit
    System.out.println("Thanx for playing"); // we output message
    continue; // skip execution of the rest (or you could use else if)
}
```

at the bottom you change while statement to stop the game if userWantToQuit is true:

```
(guess!=randomNumber && !userWantsToQuit)
```

It's been long time since I used java and I didn't test it, but it's definitely in good direction.